# Derivative of absolute value function.

Tags: calculus

If you differentiate the absolute value function the result could be the [Sign Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). By definition, the Sign Function is defined at 0, but there is no derivate of absolute value function at zero.

So, the question is: Is the Sign Function a valid function to be the derivative of absolute value? Is there another function?

Comment: You’re right, the correct derivative would be a modified sign function that’s undefined at $0$.

Comment: Or you can say the derivative is $sign(x)$ for $x\ne0$.

Comment: Why do you say that the result of differentiating the absolute value function IS the sign function then ask IF that is true?  No, since the sign function is 0 at x= 0 while the derivative of the absolute value function is not defined at x= 0 the derivative of the absolute value function is NOT the sign function!

Answer (score 4):

Since the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$, no function which *is* defined at $0$ can possibly be its derivative. But, of course, if you differentiate it, then you get the sign function at any point other than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the article you linked, it says $$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}|x|=\operatorname{sgn}x,\quad \color{red}{x\ne 0}$$
In fact $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the absolute value function is indeed not defined at $0$, but so is this representation of the sign function, that you can use as the derivative of $|x|$: $$\frac{d}{dx}|x| = \frac{|x|}{x} = \frac{x}{|x|}$$

Answer (score 1):

So far there are four answers to the first question of the OP: is the sign(x) function a valid function to be the derivative of the absolute value function? The answer is no, because the sign funftion is defined at $x = 0$ and the derivative is not. That is just formal mathematics, a matter of definitions.

The second question of the OP is constructive and in my opinion therefore more interesting: is there another function that can serve as the derivative? In other words, can we express the absolute value function in such a way that the derivative exist in $x = 0$?

The answer is yes. In mathematics there are several tricks one may use for this purpose.

A simple method is to use the Heaviside function to represent the absolute value function. For $x > 0$ we have $f = x$, and for $x < 0$ we have $f=-x$. Let us "glue" them together using the Heaviside function, to obtain:

$$f(x) = H(x)*x + (1-H(x))*-x$$

which we can rewrite as $$f(x) = (2*H(x) - 1) * x$$

We can now differentiate with respect to $x$ and obtain

$$f'(x) = 2*H(x) - 1 + 2x \delta (x)$$

where $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac delta function. This function holds for all values of $x$, in the sense that all mathematical operations (integration, differentiation etc) are well-defined and valid. The non-analytic behaviour of the derivative in $x = 0$ is of course still present, in the form of the second term.

Another method is to regard the abolute value function, with its sharp bend around $x = 0$, as the limit of a continuous function which is everywhere differentiable. It is not difficult at all to find such a continuous representation. Here is one:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt {x^2 + a^2}$$

where $a$ is an arbitrarily small parameter. Clearly the derivative $f'(x)$ now exists everywhere and can be used in calculations. At a suitable moment in the calculation the limit of $a$ to zero can be taken. Another choice is:

$$ f(x) = a * log[e^{x/a} + e^{-x/a}]$$

These methods are useful in applied mathematics, physics, engineering etc.

Comment: So what is $f’(0)$ in this construction?

Comment: Both the second and third method yield $f'(0) = 0$ trivially. The first is more tricky, because $x*\delta(x)$ describes non-analytic behaviour. Still, if you take for $\delta (x)$ a narrow Gaussian around the origin, the term can be plotted and also yields $f'(0) = 0$. Of course it is "better" not to interpret the delta function this way, and to simply use in calculations as prescribed in handbooks.

Comment: Delta function could be use this way to calculate the density function of a convolution of a random variable and a constant value. So if you sum X, a random variable and a constant can be interpret as a convolution of X by delta function.

Comment: I'm just not sure what use this is to the OP.  Maybe if you went into more detail about the advantages of the delta “function” (e.g., how it works like a derivative in integration by parts).

Answer (score 1):

Let us differentiate the absolute value function distribution style.
Write $f(x)=|x|$, then $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ so we can consider $f$ as a distribution in $\mathcal D’(\mathbb R)$. Let $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$, then by the very definition of distributional derivative we have;
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle\phi ,f’\rangle &= -\langle \phi’,f\rangle=-\int_\mathbb R \phi’(x)|x|dx= -\int_0^\infty\phi’(x)xdx +\int_{-\infty}^0\phi’(x)xdx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \phi(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(x)dx = \int_\mathbb R\phi(x)dx - 2\int_{-\infty}^0\phi(x)dx \\
&=\int_\mathbb R \phi(x)dx -2\int_\mathbb R \chi_{(-\infty,0]}(x)\phi(x)dx = \int_\mathbb R \big(\mathbf{ 1} -2\chi_{(-\infty,0]}(x)\big) \phi(x)dx\\
&=\langle\phi, \mathbf 1-2H\rangle.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We conclude that $f’ = \mathbf 1-2H$.

Here $\mathbf 1$ denotes the constant map which is constantly $1$, and $H$ denotes the heavyside function. Furthermore $\chi_A(x)$ is the indicator function on the set $A$.

Now some justifications;

- The first equality follows from the very definition of distributional derivatives.
- The third equality is just splitting up the absolute value.
- The fourth equality follows from partial integration.
- Fifth equality is just some rewriting.

Note that the heavyside function is not defined in $x=0$!

Answer (score 0):

The sign function $s(x)$ is the derivative of the function $f(x) = |x|$, **except** for the point $x=0$ where the sign function $s(x)$ is defined but $f'(x)$ is not defined.

So you could say that the sign function's domain has one extra point $x=0$ when compared to the domain of $f'(x)$, that's all.